# why mysql use just one index per table?

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I run explain on my query and I got these results :

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY bussiness   index   PRIMARY,closeBussStatus,bussStatus,approveStatus,cityID,presaleID,nameEn,DUNS,xy,subCategoryID  PRIMARY 4   NULL    295794  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY favourites  ref userID,bussID,userId_bussId bussID  4   haanet.bussiness.bussID 1   Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  rating  ref bussId  bussId  4   func    1   NULL
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  rating  ref bussId  bussId  4   func    1   Using index
```

This shows that for the first table there is a lot of possible_keys but it just choose one index. Why doesn't MySQL use more than one index for each table?

Comment: Please show the associated query.

Comment: Please post plain text whenever possible, such as the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, instead of a tiny, illegible screenshot.

Comment: @tadman ok I will do, one minute !

Comment: @wallyk I've add the query

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning.

Comment: @AndyLester ok, one minute !

Comment: @AndyLester ,I've add what you ask for ! please if you need more info tell me !

Answer (score 1):

(I'm answering the Subject; it seems that most of the details have vanished.)

Why use only one index?  Think of it this way.  Suppose you have a directory of a million persons.  Actually you had two copies, one sorted by first name, one sorted by last name.  In one list you could find the thousand (or so) entries with first name 'Rick', together with unique identifying number.  In the other list you find a thousand with last name 'James', plus the id.  Since you are looking for me, you have to somehow put those two sub-lists together to find the one id for me.  (And another id for Superfreak.)  It's messy, it involves two temp tables, possibly some sorts, etc.

The Optimizer thinks it is just simpler to go through one list, checking the rest of the WHERE clause as it goes.

But actually (in this case), a "compound" index would be even better.  That is, have one list of a million names, sorted by the combination of last name and first name:  `INDEX(last_name, first_name)`.  With that, I am easy to find.

Actually, the optimizer will *sometimes* do what I described first.  It calls it "index merge intersection".  [I discuss all these topics in a blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1).